# How to customize botium mocha timeout

Tags: selenium, testing, mocha.js

I am trying to connect to directline using the following setup:

**botium_directline.json:**

```
{
    "botium": {
      "Capabilities": {
        "PROJECTNAME": "botium-sample1",
        "CONTAINERMODE": "directline3",
        "DIRECTLINE3_SECRET": "<BOTIUM_SECRET>",
        "DIRECTLINE3_WEBSOCKET": true
      },
      "Sources": {},
      "Envs": {
        "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED": 0
      }
    }
}
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

If I run:

`botium-cli emulator browser --convos ./spec/convos --config ./botium_directline.json`

I am able to "communicate with the bot" within the new conversation.

If I wanna run the tests I prepared I get the following timeouts:
`botium-cli run --convos ./spec/convos/ --config ./botium_directline.json`

```
user @ /Users/username/workspace/testing/botium 
 ~~ npm test


> botium@1.0.0 test /Users/username/workspace/testing/botium
> botium-cli run --convos ./spec/convos/ --config ./botium_directline.json



  Botium Test-Suite
    1) Test One
    2) Test Two


  0 passing (4s)
  2 failing

  1) Botium Test-Suite
       Test One:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


  2) Botium Test-Suite
       Test Two:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

The error is similar to a standard mocha timeout error, but I do not know where to put a *.js* file to increase the timeout in a beforeEach.

I attempted to add both BOTIUM_TIMEOUT or a TIMEOUT properties into the `botium_directline.json` but this did not do anything.

Any ideas how to increase the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Botium automated tests have default timeout of 60000 milliseconds, but you can customize it by passing the --timeout flag at the end of your CLI command.

To do that, just add the flag --timeout followed by the time in milliseconds you'd like to set it up for. For instance, for 100000 milliseconds, your command should be like this: `botium-cli emulator browser --convos ./spec/convos --config ./botium_directline.json --timeout 100000`

Answer (score 0):

The "BOTIUM_TIMEOUT" environment variable is the correct choice, or you can use the "--timeout" command line switch for botium-cli. This is only available since some days, there was a bug involved which [has been fixed](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli/commit/0d994dc50786e2ab6bee79252e897da23e6f2c3d). Please get the build 0.0.34 of the botium-cli:

```
npm install botium-cli@0.0.34
```